# How do I destroy all jQuery UI widgets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget

I have developed a large "single page application" using jQuery and jQuery UI.  As I load various sections in the app it creates jQuery UI widgets like dialogs or date pickers.  They tend to hang around and cause some issues when I reload certain sections.  I would like the ability to call a function that destroys all jQuery UI widgets that have been loaded and remove them from the DOM.  Any solution to catch all of them?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory, it's easy enough to locate and destroy all widgets of a specific type on a page:

```
$(":ui-draggable").draggable("destroy");
```

So, it isn't unthinkable to create a loop around an array of widget types you know you're using, and delete every kind of widget on the list.

Answer (score 2):

Use `remove()` or `detach()` to clear the contents of your jquery UI widgets and here is the difference

[remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) removes the matched elements from the DOM completely.

[detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) is like remove(), but keeps the stored data and events associated with the matched elements.

Comment: You are calling remove() or detach() on the widgets but is this going to free all the memory used from the widgets internally or this will lead to a memory leak? - removing something from the DOM but not releasing its resources.